# Android - How to stop an activity of the other application that has been called through an intent

Tags: android

I have an intent that calls another application, but wants to stop that application after it has been called.... Is there a way to stop that application because i do not have access to that application code.

Comment: Seems to me that explaining why you want to do this would be useful - is your activity waiting for it to respond?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method.
Yes you can achieve this but you need to get the process id of that application and then kill that pid.
I think you really dont wanna get into it :)

Answer (score 0):

How can you know exactly when to stop it if your application is then in the background? AFAIK if you're launching the other application and waiting for it's response, you should implement `onActivityResult` in your activity. Have a look at: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have more specific about whether its start Activity , service or other component , because start application is not enough to understand which element you are launching .

Case "Activity" :
 launch activity will be in foregrought, so what you can do is launch other screen of your app , so this will move to background .

Case "Service" :
 unbindService() or stopService() , decision call as per the scenario .